# Read integer until it provide empty input and print out the longest increasing sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I want to write a program that read integer until the user enter empty input. Then print the longest increasing number from the input that I recieve.

example 1

```
#input
enter n: 5
enter n: 4
enter n: 3
enter n: 3
enter n: 2
enter n: 1
enter n: 

#output
3 3
```

example 2

```
#input
enter n: 5
enter n: 7
enter n: 9
enter n: 6
enter n: 8
enter n: 9
enter n: 12
enter n: 1
enter n: 3
enter n: 7
enter n: 8
enter n: 9
enter n: 9
enter n: 10
enter n: 0
enter n: 

#output
1 3 7 8 9 9 10
```

example 3

```
#input
enter n: 5
enter n: 4
enter n: 3
enter n: 2
enter n: 1
enter n: 

#output
5
```

**Here is my code**

```
numlist = []

while True:
    number = input("enter n: ")
    if number != "":
        numlist.append(int(number))
    else:
        break

if numlist == []:
    print("ERROR: please enter at least one number")

# what I'm trying to do here is that I want to group increasing numbers in the list and find the longest one.
# for example, lst = [[1,2,3,6],[2,6,8],[9,11,14]] then the longest will be [1,2,3,6]

# but I have no idea what to do next so it looks kinda confusing.
def group(p, p2):
    lst = []
    list2 = []
    for i in range(1, len(p)):
        if p[i+1] > p[i]:
            lst.append(p[i])
        else:
            list2.append(p[i])
```

What should I do next? maybe there is a better way to write this program?? (ಥ_ʖಥ)

Comment: You don't really need to keep every number.  All you need to keep is (a) the current increasing sublist, and (b) the longest list.  If the new number is not less than the end of the current sequence, add it.  Otherwise, you'll need to start a new list; if the list you've just finished in longer than the longest, save it.

Comment: Remember that an empty list is equal to `[]`, not `['']`.

Answer (score 2):

An example based on my comment:

```
curlist = []
longest = []

while True:
    number = input("enter n: ")
    if not number: break
    number = int(number)
    if curlist and number < curlist[-1]:
        if len(curlist) > len(longest):
            longest = curlist
        curlist = []
    curlist.append( number )

if len(curlist) > len(longest):
    longest = curlist

print( longest )
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Can you also explain this part? if curlist and number < curlist[-1]. curlist is list, what I want to know is that how can we compare the whole list with curlist[-1] which is the last item?

Comment: You don't need to "compare the whole list" with anything.  If `number` is greater than or equal to the last element, then it continues an increasing sequence.  We keep building that sequence until the next number is lower than the last element.  We then we check to see if the sublist we just finished is longer than the longest we already collected.

Comment: Think about a human doing this task.  Let's say you have {1 2] written down.  The user hands you 3.  You check that against the last element you wrote down.  3 > 2, so you write down [1 2 3].  Now the user hands you 1.  Whoops, that's lower than the last element, so we need to start a new sequence.  We remember [1 2 3] as the longest sequence we've seen, and start a new list with [1].

Comment: Oh, and the `if curlist` part handles our very first time through.  If `curlist` is empty, then `curlist[-1]` is not valid, so I make sure `curlist` has something in it before checking it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for the same:

```
numlist = []

while True:
    number = input("enter n: ")
    if number != "":
        numlist.append(int(number))
    else:
        break

if numlist == []:
    print("ERROR: please enter at least one number")

longest = []
interlist = [numlist[0]]
for i in range(1, len(numlist)):
    if numlist[i]>=interlist[-1]:
        interlist.append(numlist[i])
    else:
        longest.append(interlist)
        interlist = [numlist[i]]
longest.append(interlist)
longest_data = longest[0]
for data in longest:
    if len(data) > len(longest_data):
        longest_data = data
print (longest_data)
```

Output:

```
enter n: 5
enter n: 6
enter n: 7
enter n: 8
enter n: 12
enter n: 1
enter n: 2
enter n: 3
enter n: 4
enter n: 4
enter n: 5
enter n: 6
enter n: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: No Problem! Make sure you upvote/accept the answer which has helped you so that the person helping you gets the credits for his work.. :-)